# Preheader isn't appearing in Inbox

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, email, html, help

I was trying to discover why preheaders of my new Marketing Cloud customer, isn't appears on email inbox.

First I duplicated one of the emails they are used to send and inserted a preheader test message, then I tryed to insert the subject and preheader using some AMPSCRIPT synthax and the preheader still dosen't appear.
[image]

[image]

I think my customer did something wrong on this standard HTML code (they always use this one), because I tested using one of the Marketing Cloud templates and inserted a subject and a preheader on the email, and when I sent a test the preheaders appeared.

[image]

[image]

I created a case to get some answer to this problem but the technician couldn't help me and he asked me to look here, but I didn't find any discussion that helps me. Does anybody know how to fix it, please?

Comment: Also this https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321251&type=1

Comment: I wish I had a job where I could just send people to stackExchange :D :D

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to set the `@preheader` value before the `<body>` tag in your email, since it gets inserted directly after the `<body>` prior to the send.

Or you can leave the Email definition input box blank and [hardcode your own value](https://www.litmus.com/blog/the-little-known-preview-text-hack-you-may-want-to-use-in-every-email/) right after the `<body>` tag, which I've seen done quite a bit to tweak the Gmail pre-header output.  The base SFMC functionality doesn't do this:

```html
<body>
<div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
Insert hidden preheader text here.
</div>
 
<!-- Insert &#847;&zwnj;&nbsp; hack after hidden preview text -->
<div style="display: none; max-height: 0px; overflow: hidden;">
&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;&#847;&zwnj;&nbsp;
</div>

<!-- other HTML -->

</body>
```